# Xcode 6 can't uncomment string with //

Tags: swift, xcode6

Using Xcode 6.x, the comment command <kbd>COMMAND</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> allows you to comment and uncomment lines of code. But if the line contains a string with `"//"`, like a URL, <kbd>COMMAND</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> just adds more comments.

```
var test = "http://test"
```

<kbd>COMMAND</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> will comment the line. (correctly)

```
//     var test = "http://test"
```

If you <kbd>COMMAND</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> again, you'll get more comments.

```
////   var test = "http://test"
```

What is going on? Is there a fix for this?

Comment: It's a bug in Xcode, not something you're generally going to find a fix for. In this case though, upgrade to the 6.3 beta, they seem to have fixed this in the new version.

Comment: I've had similar issues. Sometimes manually going to Editor>Structure>Comment Selection with the text highlighted will fix it for the next time you go to use the hot key. Also, its CMD + / not CTRL + /

Comment: @DanielStorm,  Sorry. I was looking at my external windows keyboard. :P

Comment: Thanks for teaching me about `<kbd>key</kbd>` haha!

Comment: Why not just delete the unwanted characters?

Answer (score 0):

This is an Xcode bug.

It got fixed as of Xcode 6.3